# Alignment when writing complicated linear systems of equations

Tags: matrices

I have the following code which can generate pdf as the figure shows. However, it lacks some alignments I want. I knew there is systeme package which may be useful, yet I found it didn't work for this case. So how to get what I want as the red pen shows?

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{align}\label{eq:laplace-qem}
    (L_{ijr}^{T}L_{ijr}+\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{11} & 0\\0 & 0 \end{array}\right])\mathbf{v}_{er,x}
    +\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{12} & 0\\0 & 0 \end{array}\right]\mathbf{v}_{er,y}
    +\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{13} & 0\\0 & 0 \end{array}\right]\mathbf{v}_{er,z}
    +\left[\begin{array}{c}v_{e,g}q_{14}+q_{15}\\0\end{array}\right]
    +L_{ijr}^{T}b_{x} = 0 \\
    \left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{12} & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]\mathbf{v}_{er,x}
    +(L_{ijr}^{T}L_{ijr}+\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{22} & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right])\mathbf{v}_{er,y}
    +\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{23} & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]\mathbf{v}_{er,z}
    +\left[\begin{array}{c}v_{e,g}q_{24}+q_{25}\\0\end{array}\right]
    +L_{ijr}^{T}b_{y} = 0 \\
    \left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{13} & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]\mathbf{v}_{er,x}
    +\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{23} & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]\mathbf{v}_{er,y}
    +(L_{ijr}^{T}L_{ijr}+\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{33} & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right])\mathbf{v}_{er,z}
    +\left[\begin{array}{c}v_{e,g}q_{34}+q_{35}\\0\end{array}\right]
    +L_{ijr}^{T}b_{z} = 0 \\
    \left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{14} & 0\end{array}\right]\mathbf{v}_{er,x}
    +\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{24} & 0\end{array}\right]\mathbf{v}_{er,y}
    +\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{34} & 0\end{array}\right]\mathbf{v}_{er,z}
    +q_{44}v_{e,g}
    +q_{45} = 0
\end{align}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the equation numbering, you use the `align*` environment. To align at certain places, you use the `&` symbol. You can look at page 4 of the `amsmath` package [documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) to see examples of how to align different equations. I also took this opportunity to insert `\left(` and `\right)` to make the `()` the correct size with respect to the array. See the updated example which does what you want.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{align*}\label{eq:laplace-qem}
    \left(L_{ijr}^{T}L_{ijr}+\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{11} & 0\\0 & 0 \end{array}\right]\right)&\mathbf{v}_{er,x}&
    +\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{12} & 0\\0 & 0 \end{array}\right]&\mathbf{v}_{er,y}&
    +\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{13} & 0\\0 & 0 \end{array}\right]&\mathbf{v}_{er,z}&
    +\left[\begin{array}{c}v_{e,g}q_{14}+q_{15}\\0\end{array}\right]
    +L_{ijr}^{T}b_{x} = 0 \\
    \left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{12} & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]&\mathbf{v}_{er,x}&
    +\left(L_{ijr}^{T}L_{ijr}+\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{22} & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]\right)&\mathbf{v}_{er,y}&
    +\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{23} & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]&\mathbf{v}_{er,z}&
    +\left[\begin{array}{c}v_{e,g}q_{24}+q_{25}\\0\end{array}\right]
    +L_{ijr}^{T}b_{y} = 0 \\
    \left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{13} & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]&\mathbf{v}_{er,x}&
    +\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{23} & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]&\mathbf{v}_{er,y}&
    +\left(L_{ijr}^{T}L_{ijr}+\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{33} & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]\right)&\mathbf{v}_{er,z}&
    +\left[\begin{array}{c}v_{e,g}q_{34}+q_{35}\\0\end{array}\right]
    +L_{ijr}^{T}b_{z} = 0 \\
    \left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{14} & 0\end{array}\right]&\mathbf{v}_{er,x}&
    +\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{24} & 0\end{array}\right]&\mathbf{v}_{er,y}&
    +\left[\begin{array}{cc}q_{34} & 0\end{array}\right]&\mathbf{v}_{er,z}&
    +q_{44}v_{e,g}
    +q_{45} = 0
\end{align*}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

This should be an `array`; note that `bmatrix` gives a better result than `array` for matrices.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape,array}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\[
\begin{array}{
  @{}
  r % coefficient
  @{}
  l % variable
  @{}
  *{2}{>{{}}r@{}l@{}} % two similar groups
  >{{}}r % other terms
  @{}
  >{{}}l % equals 0
}
\left(L_{ijr}^{T}L_{ijr}+\begin{bmatrix}q_{11} & 0\\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right)&\mathbf{v}_{er,x}&
    +\begin{bmatrix}q_{12} & 0\\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}&\mathbf{v}_{er,y}&
    +\begin{bmatrix}q_{13} & 0\\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}&\mathbf{v}_{er,z}&
    +\begin{bmatrix}v_{e,g}q_{14}+q_{15}\\0\end{bmatrix}
    +L_{ijr}^{T}b_{x} &= 0 \\[3.5ex]
    \begin{bmatrix}q_{12} & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}&\mathbf{v}_{er,x}&
    +\left(L_{ijr}^{T}L_{ijr}+\begin{bmatrix}q_{22} & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\right)&\mathbf{v}_{er,y}&
    +\begin{bmatrix}q_{23} & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}&\mathbf{v}_{er,z}&
    +\begin{bmatrix}v_{e,g}q_{24}+q_{25}\\0\end{bmatrix}
    +L_{ijr}^{T}b_{y} &= 0 \\[3.5ex]
    \begin{bmatrix}q_{13} & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}&\mathbf{v}_{er,x}&
    +\begin{bmatrix}q_{23} & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}&\mathbf{v}_{er,y}&
    +\left(L_{ijr}^{T}L_{ijr}+\begin{bmatrix}q_{33} & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\right)&\mathbf{v}_{er,z}&
    +\begin{bmatrix}v_{e,g}q_{34}+q_{35}\\0\end{bmatrix}
    +L_{ijr}^{T}b_{z} &= 0 \\[3.5ex]
    \begin{bmatrix}q_{14} & 0\end{bmatrix}&\mathbf{v}_{er,x}&
    +\begin{bmatrix}q_{24} & 0\end{bmatrix}&\mathbf{v}_{er,y}&
    +\begin{bmatrix}q_{34} & 0\end{bmatrix}&\mathbf{v}_{er,z}&
    +q_{44}v_{e,g}
    +q_{45} &= 0
\end{array}
\]
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]